# How to open menu link in web part

Tags: html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I am completely new to SP. I want to open link from menu panel (Introduction) in Web Part (SiteFeed). There is simple .html page in this link. I used to use frames in HTML, but here I have no idea how to direct link to an element. Is possible to connect link with Wep Part this way? If yes, how?

Thanks a lot in advance

[image]